# Can I deploy Django to Heroku with Windows

Tags: python, django, heroku, web

I am trying to see whether I can deploy a Django app on Heroku if I have a Windows machine. IN the Getting Started With Django article https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django it says to use Gunicorn, but Gunicorn is only for Unix machines and I have a lot of issues with this tutorial. Can anyone give their experience with deploying Django on Heroku with Windows 7?

Comment: My first recommendation would be to create a vagrant virtual box, it will allow you to develop closer to most hosting / deployment scenarios.
It's really easy to install and keeps also your system clean.
If not, there are alternate ways to deploy django, you can see Apache solutions (haven't tested any, since I use gunicorn).

Comment: Apart from the above, check the Heroku documentation (again I haven't tried Heroku): https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django

Comment: Why would it matter whether gunicorn can run on Windows? For deployment to Heroku, all you need to care about is whether git runs on Windows, which it does.

Comment: @DanielRoseman There are a lot of issues especially with the foreman start command. I have added heroku bin to my path and downgraded my foreman to 0.61. Still I face issues with that command in git. I feel like windows users are kind of left behind with this tutorial.

Comment: But that has nothing to do with deployment, that's for running your site locally. If gunicorn doesn't work you can just use the Django runserver until it's time to actually deploy.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yeah just figured that out. After I add the code to the bottom of my settings.py and wsgi.py files can I just start development?